# On background color change listener - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, event-listener

**How can I create a listener for the background color change of my view?**

I have this approach and it doesn't work:

```
init {
    subject.setTag(subject.background);
    subject.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val newVis: Int = (subject.background as ColorDrawable).color
        if ((subject.getTag() as ColorDrawable).color != newVis) {
            subject.setTag(subject.background)
            notifySourceChanged()
        }
    })
}
```

where **subject** is my View.
Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: It's a long story. In a few words, I can navigate forward only if my view's background color is changed.

Comment: I think you must notify the navigation when you change the color, for example, if the ViewModel or presenter update the view state, the ViewModel or presenter must notify to activity / fragment do the navigation too